# In Expo / React Native, how to retrieve an ImageData from an image file?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In React Native / Expo Managed App, I need to retrieve the **ImageData** from an image file, the ImageData should be formatted like this:

```
export type ImageData = {
  readonly data: Uint8ClampedArray
  readonly height: number
  readonly width: number
}
```

We can use the Expo FileSystem to retrieve a string in base64 of the image:

```
const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(result.uri, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

But I don't this how to convert it to an `ImageData` type

Any idea on how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileSystem in Expo:

```
const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(result.uri, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

Comment: Hello thanks but I forgot to mention that I was using Expo... in which we cannot use "react-native-fs", I just updated the title

Comment: + can you be sure that "data" is in ImageData format ?

Comment: It's normal base64 image data. For example, "data:image/png,ABQCAIAAABtUGDWAA...".

Comment: I will test it out with this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssim.js/v/3.4.0 where the ssim function takes two images **as DataImage** format

Comment: In Expo, you can use FileSystem. I updated my solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this readAsStringAsync returns a string, I need a ImageData type

Comment: I completly changed my initial post, I should re-create a fresh post maybe ? not sure I will get answers after these edits